# Is a function with a decreasing amplitude periodic?

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-functions

For example, is the function $\frac{\sin x}x$ periodic? Using the the definition of periodic functions that $f(x)=f(x+p)$, the following must be true if the function is periodic:

$\frac{\sin x}x=\frac{\sin (x+p)}{x+p} = \frac{\sin (x)\cos (p)+\sin (p)\cos (x)}{x+p}$

This means that the following must be true for the equation to be true:

$\sin p = 0$

$\therefore p = 2\pi n$

$\cos p = 1$

$\therefore p = 2\pi n$

$p = 0$ (for the denominator to be equal)

Which gives a consistent result only if $p=0$. It can also be seen that the denominator is responsible only for changing amplitude and if the function is graphed it has a consistent period. Is the function periodic?

Comment: the function $\frac{sin x}{x}$ is not periodic

Comment: So is any function with a decreasing amplitude not periodic?

Comment: If the amplitude is decreasing, then the function values do not repeat exactly.  So the function is not periodic.

Comment: @kyczawon Think about it this way. If the function had been periodic, it would arguably be $2\pi$. This means if I "pick up" the graph, put it $2\pi$ to the left and then put it down, I would get exactly the same graph, or stated  a tad differently, the graph would coincide with its original. That won't happen here, so not periodic

Comment: By definition, the period P must be non-zero. And the definition upholds the meaning of the word *'periodic'*. Calling your function as periodic would essentially be pointless.

Comment: You more or less have proved it is not periodic by showing $f(x+p) = f(x)$ only for $p=0$,